# Can I make drivers read values from textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, drivers

Is it possible to read RGB values from a pixel of a texture using UV coordinates and use that in drivers? Python code?

I'd like to create a driver to influence object's locations, rotation and visibility, but the only input I have is through a texture.

I'm using a special project template with certain points on the texture feeding color or B/W values for materials. I'd like to use the same texture to convey some values to drivers - changing the geometry of the scene, not only materials.

Comment: Sure, a PyDriver can access image pixels. I am skeptical that the scene will update correctly on frame change, but at render time it should update ok.

Comment: I only render single frames. But I select the frame depending on some other stuff. I'll either render frame 1 or 2, but all textures are static.
Could you proved an example or direct me to some sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each image datablock in Blender has a `pixels` property. This is an array of pixels starting from the bottom row left to right.

The RGBA values of a pixels are listed after one another. The RGBA values for the bottom-left pixels will be indiced with 0, 1, 2 and 3. The RGBA values of the second pixels can be called with the indices 4, 5, 6, 7 from the pixel list.

Starting with [this](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.de/2012/08/adjusting-image-pixels-internally-in.html) post, [this blog](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.de/search/label/bpy.data.images) has lots of informations about pixels in bpy.data.images.

I have created a sample script which manipulates the object location based on frames of an images. (Compare the attached file.)

```
import bpy

def updateFromImage(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current
    obj = scene.objects['Cube']

    pixels = bpy.data.images['InputImage'].pixels

    # read the green pixels
    greenPixelAtFrameNo = pixels[frame*4 + 1]
    obj.location.z = greenPixelAtFrameNo * 5
    obj.location.x = frame



bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(updateFromImage)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Looks like the pixels[] array is one-dimensional, which is a bit strange to allocate 6-dimensional dataset (X,Y,R,G,B,A) but your example shows how to access all I need.
I need to know the image resolution thought to be able to interpret the table properly.

I tried using this:
bpy.data.images[].resolution

But it gives me strange values:

>>> bpy.data.images['InputImage'].resolution
Vector((2835.0, 2835.0))

for your demo image that is 16x16 pixels big.
I don't know what is this.

Comment: Check out this (http://blenderscripting.blogspot.de/2012/08/faster-pixel-manipulation-inside-blender.html) entry in the blog I linked. He writes a method to get pixels by coordinates. Instead of resolution that property you need is "size". "size[0]" is the width and "size[1]" the height in pixels. So to get a pixel at e.g. (12, 10) you need to calculate the index with: ((12-1) * size[0] + 10) * 4. Should I extend my answer with methods to get specific pixels or can you already continue with this?